# Generic typescript type definition incl. a primitive type

Tags: typescript, generics, types

Just a simple question. I need a class that is generic over some type `T`. `T` should be either a `string` or some subclass of type `Bar`. However, if I write it as follows, `T` resolves to `T extends Bar` or `T extends string`.

```
class Foo<T extends Bar | string> {
    run(data: T): void { ... }
}
```

What is the correct way of writing it so that `T` resolves to `T extends Bar` or `string`?

Comment: Where's the problem? `let f = new Foo<string>();` is totally valid

Comment: You are completely right. This works and I will most likely leave it that way. But it does not really answer the question as there is a difference in the typing that I am now using and the typing I would like to use and I would be curious to know how to properly type it...

Comment: Is there really a difference? I mean, string is a primitive type means you can't derive from it: so `T extends string` will always ONLY allow `string`. (Or in your case: Bar). SO I don't really get it: what's the difference in the typings?

Comment: Actually you are right. In this case it collapses to the same semantics. It would be a bit different if the 2nd type would not be a primitive type. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: In the sense that string literal types extend string, it is in fact not the same. However, it should be close enough.

Answer (score 0):

Having type `T extends string` allows to do this (basically restrict run method to be called with specific string literal type)

```js
type Bar = {
  a: string
}

class Foo<T extends Bar | string> {
  run(data: T): void {
    console.log(data)
  }
}

const fooBar = new Foo<'bar'>()
const fooString = new Foo<string>()

fooBar.run('bar') // compiles
fooBar.run('baz') // does not compile

fooString.run('bar') // compiles
fooString.run('baz') // compiles
```

If you dont want this semantic, you can very well have following typing

```js
class Foo<T extends Bar> {
  run(data: T | string): void {
    console.log(data)
  }
}

const fooBar = new Foo()

fooBar.run('bar') // compiles
fooBar.run('baz') // compiles
```